# How can I add an item from a List into a Session in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Right now I've got a CheckBoxList which is dynamically populated with information based on a search from the user. After the user checks items on the list and presses a button, I want to add that item to a list which is saved between postbacks. I (think) I've correctly created a Session and saved a list to it, but I need to know how to then add to that list properly. Still very new to ASP.NET.

```
List<Book> currentBookSelection;
List<Book> finalBooklist;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Session["booklist"] == null) {
        finalBooklist = new List<Book>();
        Session.Add("booklist", finalBooklist);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("FINAL Booklist Session created.");
    } else {
        finalBooklist = Session["booklist"] as List<Book>;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("FINAL Booklist Session ALREADY created.");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Number of books in FINAL: " + finalBooklist.Count());
    }

    currentBookSelection = new List<Book>();
}
```

This next part is a snippet from the method used to pull information (saved as strings) via a forloop for each item on the checkbox saved as strings - and added to an object of a custom class.

```
cblResults.Items.Add(bookTitle);
currentBookSelection.Add(new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPrice, bookCoverURL, bookISBN, bookNumPages, bookAmazonURL));
```

Finally, when the user presses the button... If the user checks a box, find the object in currentBookSelection with the same title, and then add that object to the finalBooklist - which should be persistent across refreshes/postbacks.

```
protected void btnAddSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach (ListItem item in cblResults.Items) {
        if (item.Selected) {
            foreach (Book book in currentBookSelection) {
                if (book.title == item.Text) {
                    finalBooklist.Add(book);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(book.title + " added to FinalBooklist");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Button click event finished.");
    cblResults.Items.Clear();
}
```

**SOLUTION:** I had to save my currentBookSelection into a Session as well - or else when I pressed the button it would simply return back to size 0. Thanks to @Steve and the others for the help!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Session["finalbooklist"] == null) {
        finalBooklist = new List<Book>();
        Session.Add("finalbooklist", finalBooklist);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("FINAL Booklist Session created.");
    } else {
        finalBooklist = Session["finalbooklist"] as List<Book>;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Number of books in FINAL: " + finalBooklist.Count());
        PrintFinalBookList();
    }

    if (Session["currentbooklist"] == null) {
        currentBookSelection = new List<Book>();
        Session.Add("currentbooklist", currentBookSelection);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("CURRENT Booklist created");
    } else {
        currentBookSelection = Session["currentbooklist"] as List<Book>;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Number of books in CURRENT: " + currentBookSelection.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can store a `List<T>` as a session value.  You probably have to store each value inside that list as a different session value.  A couple examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525095(v=vs.90).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstateitemcollection.aspx).  It would be easier to display all of the values the `List<T>` on a web control so the user could see them as well.

Comment: What happens now? Do your Session["booklist"] works as expected or not?

Comment: I think that your variable _currentBookSelection_ is always empty when you reach the _btnAddSelected_Click_ If that variable is reinitialized in the Page_Load every time then you loose the content of the List at each Page_Load

Comment: At the moment it won't add the book from 'currentBookSelection' to the 'finalBooklist'. All other events in the button handler (my debug code, for example) works, just not the code populated in the (foreach Book in currentBookSelection)...

As for whether you can use lists, I thought this was the case. Other SO answers seem to imply that it is.

Comment: As for losing the content, the intent is that after the user presses the 'Add' button, it will add the selection to the final and then clear the check box so the user can carry out more searches. I don't know if it's working as it should be, though.

Comment: is the type Book serializable?

Comment: Not currently, no. To be honest I'm not entirely sure what Serializable even is/does, so I didn't add it - still new to all this, somewhat.

Comment: @Vigilant put breakpoint in the Page_Load event, in the btnAddSelected_Click event and where you add the book to the _currentBookSelection_ list.  You should be able to see the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) in action. You should save in the Session object also the _currentBookSelection_ list

Comment: Today I learned the power of breakpoints. It was indeed resetting the currentBookSelection back to size 0 when I pressed the bottom, on page reload. I've now added a second Session - which I've added to my initial question above. The solution works, though I'm curious if I'm doing more work than I need to - do I need to create a second Session["currentBookList"], or is there a way to associate both lists with a single Session? I think I tried to do Session.Add("booklist", currentBookSelection), to add it to the one that finalBookList was also on, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just create a new class where two properties are the two lists. Then create an instance of that class and add it to an unique Session variable

Comment: Thanks so much - that's brilliant, and works like a charm.